# Are these break statements odd?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm new to using the `try`, `except` and `break`statements, the code below works just fine, but I'm wondering if the `break`statements at the end of the while(s) are correct.

```py
nombre = ""
edad = None
genero = None

    while len(nombre) == 0:
        try:
            nombre = str(input("\n█ Ingrese el nombre: "))
            if len(nombre) == 0:
                raise ValueError

        except ValueError:
            print(
                "\n» » » El valor ingresado no es inválido, intente nuevamente « « «\n"
            )
        else:
            break

    while type(edad) is not int:

        try:
            edad = int(input("\n█ Ingrese la edad: "))

        except ValueError:
            print(
                "\n» » » El valor ingresado no es un número entero, intente nuevamente « « «\n"
            )

        else:
            break

    while genero not in ["HOMBRE", "MUJER"]:
        try:
            genero = str(input("\n█ Ingrese el género: ")).upper()
            if genero != "HOMBRE" or genero != "MUJER":
                raise ValueError

        except ValueError:
            print(
                '\n» » » El valor ingresado debe ser "Hombre" o "Mujer", intente nuevamente « « «\n'
            )
        else:
            break
```

Please ignore the language as Spanish is my mother tongue.

Comment: Why raise an error if you’re going to catch it immediately?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have corrected it with the help of blhsing.

Answer (score 2):

There's no good reason to use exception handling here. Since you're simply raising an exception on an `if` condition just to catch it in the next line, you might as well do the error handling after `if` fails to validate the input. Otherwise `break` when `if` successfully validates the input.

Using your first `while` loop as an example:

```
while True:
    nombre = input("\n█ Ingrese el nombre: ")
    if nombre:
        break
    print("\n» » » El valor ingresado no es inválido, intente nuevamente « « «\n")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was mainly using to to raise ValueError is the string was empty... but `if nombre:` apparently does the same, cool.

Comment: _I was mainly using to to raise ValueError is the string was empty... but if nombre: apparently does the same, cool._ That's not the important part though, you could have stuck to using `len()` just fine.